# Altering the main query using get_post_meta() in pre_get_posts

Tags: pre-get-posts

I need a reliable way to get the post ID outside of the loop to use `get_post_meta()` in the `pre_get_posts` hook.

So far I found out that

- `get_queried_object_id()` works for all pages except the frontpage or blogpage
- `get_option( 'page_on_front' )` gives the frontpage ID
- `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )` gives the blogpage ID
- `global $post; echo $post->ID;` seems not to work with `pre_get_posts` (no idea why)

I tried to check the ID conditionally with different functions:

```
function show_id ( $wp_query ) {

if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    // Default homepage
    $id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    // static homepage
    $id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    // blog page
    $id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
} else {
    //everything else
    $id = get_queried_object_id();  
}
// Debug
echo $id;
}
add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_id' );
```

It works for the blogpage and other pages but not for the static frontpage. I get these error notifications:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\wp-includes\query.php on line 4520
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\wp-includes\query.php on line 4522
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\wp-includes\query.php on line 4524

Can you help?

**Edit:**

What I want to achive is to call `get_post_meta()` at `pre_get_posts` which will return an array of post IDs. Then I want to modify the main query with something like `$query->set ('post__in', array($myIDs));` to get the posts based on the IDs in the metadata of the queried post.

Comment: What kind of post meta do you _need_ in a pre_get_posts hook? Why not save it as an option? Your errors probably relate to [this bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29660) in which get_queried_object() has the possibility of returning `NULL` to one of the normal conditionals. Have you tried `$wp_query->is_front_page()` instead?

Comment: The meta value will contain an array of post IDs. I want to get these IDs and use `$query->set ('post__in', array($myIDs));` to alter the main query.

Comment: Do you set this on a post by post basis? If not it would be easier and probably better suited as an option then you could just use `get_option()` and be done with the whole thing.

Comment: The metadata wil be applied to a CPT without any requirements to page or post attributes. If I modify the question, can you give an example?

Comment: How are you saving the postmeta? via plugin or by the `save_post` hook or custom fields or...?

Comment: I use CMB2 with [attached-posts](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/cmb2-attached-posts)

Comment: Sorry I have to correct this the metadata will be applied to pages not CPT.

Comment: As the question about the IDs was answered your example would be offtopic, but thank you for the input i will look into how to use `get_option` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the wordpress codex [pre_get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) does not work everywhere.

`is_font_page()` will not work but `is_home()` will. So your condition `is_front_page() && is_home()` will fail every time. However 'is_home()' alone should work.

It might be helpful to others to know what exactly you are trying to do. Usually pre_get_posts is used to alter a query but from the snippet of code you have shared. All I can tell you are trying to do is get a post id of for a page that has a list of posts on it?

One more thing. I loaded your function within a theme I am working on and the function fired about 5 times in various places where new queries are made like the nav menu and sidebar. So you also need to be aware of what query you are in. You should probably use this to ensure you are in the main query.

```
if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
    //check if home or else where here
}
```

I see you have added more info in the comments of your question which I am unable to comment in since my reputation is too low at this point.

If I were you I would target the homepage a different way. Maybe a custom template file and then set your query for that page with [query_posts($args)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) and build your own loop.

**Added Working Function Accepted in Chat:**

```
function show_id ( $wp_query ) {
// lets make sure we are in the main query
if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
    if (  is_home() ) {
        // Default homepage or blog Archive
        $id = $id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );;
    } elseif ( !is_single() && !empty($wp_query->query_vars['page_id'])) {
        // static homepage aka front page
        $id = $wp_query->query_vars['page_id'];
    } else {
        //everything else
        $id = get_queried_object_id();  
    }
}
// Debug
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($id);
//var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['page_id']);
//var_dump($wp_query);
echo '</pre>';
}
add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_id' );
```

Comment: For the moment I just wanted to know how to securely get post IDs so I can use them for `get_post_meta`, which will be used to alter the query within `pre_get_posts`. I agree with you I should clarify what I want to do in the question.

Comment: So this works on single pages but not on Home/Front page or Blog Archives? BTW I have edited my answer a little.

Comment: The IDs  show independant of the used template for all pages except the one for the frontpage. Didnt test it but generic archiv pages dont have an ID as far as I know.

Comment: Thats correct, the archives page is used to display paged based on searches and a archives of terms. So it seems you just need to resolve this for home and for blog?

Comment: I need a reliable function so no matter in what context the page is it will return the post ID.

Comment: The problem is there isnt one, pre_get_posts() fires before some of the template pages load, so the query is empty.

Comment: I would make a tempalte file for front-page.php (static homepage) and for home.php (blog page). You can copy the index.php file and make them. Then you can design your query to work as you wish.

Comment: You can get the IDs. Use the functions above isolated to see. Problem occurs with conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40070/discussion-between-stoi2m1-and-jekyll).

Comment: I would like to stick to the standard loop and modify it conditionally with filters/actions. Of course custom template are another way to do this.